# Python create xml from xsd

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I am new with python and need to implement an interface to an accounting tool. I received some XSD Files which describes the interface.

What is the easiest way to generate the XML according to the XSD?
Is there any module I can use?

Do I have to create the XML all by myself and I can use the XSD just to verify it?
How do I best proceed?

Comment: Take a look into PyXb. Xml schema bindings for python.

Answer (score 5):

I think, [generateDS](http://www.davekuhlman.org/generateDS.html) is the solution to your problem. 
Starting from chapter 5, the command

```
python generateDS.py -o people.py -s peoplesubs.py people.xsd
```

reads the XSD file and creates several classes and subclasses. It generates many data structures and getters and setters for accessing and using data :)
If there is any XML file that complies with that XSD, it can be read straight away by using

```
import people
rootObject = people.parse('people.xml')
```

within the code. More information is given in chapter 12.
The aforementioned classes also provide methods to export data as an XML format.
The level of documentation is good and it is highly suggested to use this for any future project.

Comment: I think you are missing the point in the question. The OP is asking how to generate an XML (an instance of a schema) from the XSD file. In your answer that would be the generation of `people.xml` through `people.xsd`.

Comment: I guess that missing part of the answer would be `rootObject.export('people.xml')`. generating an xml without having data is not possible. // i like the answer. it pointed me to a very complete and easy-to-use framework

Answer (score 0):

There are some projects on github that do that by using xmlschema library, for instance [fortesp/xsd2xml](https://github.com/fortesp/xsd2xml) or [miaozn/xsd2xml (python2)](https://github.com/miaozn/xsd2xml)

For instance with the former:

```
xmlgenerator = XMLGenerator('resources/pain.001.001.09.xsd', True, DataFacet())
print(xmlgenerator.execute()) # Output to console
xmlgenerator.write('filename.xml') # Output to file
```

Unfortunately none of these are properly packaged though.

Comment: What is DataFacet(). I cann't find this in any file.