# Creating a xml file based on a schema using Python

Tags: python, xml

I am very new to working with xml file format and need some basic help.

I am trying to create a xml file from scratch based on a xsd schema and then fill it with some test content for now. The schema I want to follow is the eSDScom xml schema (https://github.com/esdscom/sdscom-xml). What I need is a very basic code example to get me started how to create a valid eSDScom xml file with some content.

Comment: Hi. Review related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48928973/543969) and  [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17106/543969).

Comment: Requests to be pointed at generic examples are generally considered off-topic, either by way of being too broad/unclear for there to be a definitive way anyone but you can judge whether a given answer is responsive to the question, or by way of being an off-site resource request. Show a _narrow, specific_ problem you encountered while trying to follow the documentation; where do you get stuck, such that you _need_ an example?